# GroupBy date for datetime row in python pandas

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I want to generate the sum of distance and seconds traveled by day. I want to use a groupby function to calculate the sum of the orders per day.

I have the following code:

```
import pandas as pd

orders = pd.read_csv('complete.csv', delimiter=',', encoding='ISO-8859-1')

orders['datetime'] = pd.to_datetime(orders['datetime'])

orders.groupby(orders.datetime.dt.date).sum()
print(orders)
```

The complete csv file looks as follow:

```
datetime,restaurant,customer_address,amount,restaurant_address,meters,seconds
2018-01-01 15:41:37,Name,9711AR,50.5,9722AC,2268.3,606.0
2018-08-13 16:57:52,Name,9711AR,22.3,9722AC,2268.3,606.0
2018-09-21 17:38:53,Name,9711AR,66.89,9722AC,2268.3,606.0
2018-11-09 18:37:26,Name,9711AR,42.66,9722AC,2268.3,606.0
2018-01-01 18:28:04,Name,9711AJ,70.75,9746RD,4090.4,1039.5
```

I want to generate a sum of meters and seconds for each day.

I think I have some trouble with the 'datetime' object that it does not recognize it as a date or something.

Any ideas?

Comment: what is wrong with `orders.groupby(orders.datetime.dt.date)[['meters','seconds']].sum()` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your code is good, the only issue is that `orders.groupby(orders.datetime.dt.date).sum()` do not update orders, you can add 
`orders = orders.groupby(orders.datetime.dt.date).sum()` if you want to do so